# Custom post type with taxonomy template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Can I create different pages for a custom post type based on its taxonomies?

For instance:

- my custom post types is 'courses'
- 'courses' pages are 'python', 'php', 'java'
- a 'courses' taxonomy is 'level', with this list:'beginner','advanced','professional'
- the default custom post type page is http://example.com/courses/python/
- I need new dynamic pages like http://example.com/courses/python/advanced, http://example.com/courses/php/beginner etc...

I've tried to add a custom permalink with /%level% at the end, but this is not a good solution, as I need to keep the default page and to show different pages for each level.

Comment: No, in the WordPress ecosystem `/courses/python/advanced/` would be a child page of `/courses/python/`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any workaround to achieve the same result dinamically?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could still use the taxonomies to *label* the child pages with their assigned level to include level-specific content in the PHP templates.